# How to mark parent tree node as selected if all the child nodes are selected

Tags: javascript, tree

I have a json that forms a tree.

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: "A",
    isSelected: false,
    child: [
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "B",
            isSelected: false,
        }
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "C",
            isSelected: false,
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 4,
    name: "D",
    isSelected: false,
    child: [
        {
            id: 5,
            name: "E",
            isSelected: false,
        }
        {
            id: 6,
            name: "F",
            isSelected: false,
        }
    ]
}]
```

Now I have an array of selected nodes

```
[{id: 2},{id:3}]
```

And `markSelectedNodes` method to mark the nodes as selected based on selected node array

```
markSelectedNodes(_nodes) {
    _nodes.forEach((_node) => {
        // match if node exists in selected nodes
        const _isFound = this.selectedNodes.find((_selectedNode) => _selectedNode.id === _node.id);
        if (_isFound) {
            _node.isSelected = true;
        } else {
            _node.isSelected = false;
        }
        // removed the node from selecedNode list as this has been marked selected
        this.selectedNodes = this.selectedNodes.filter((_selectedNode) => _selectedNode !== _node.id);

        // go through the child
        if (_node.child && _node.child.length) {
            this.markSelectedNodes(_node.child);
        }
    });
}
```

Now if all the child has been marked selected it should also mark the parent node as selected.

Can this be implemented through stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach and check if every item is selected for updating the parent node.

```js
function update(array = [], ids) {
    return !!array.length
        && array.every(node => node.isSelected = ids.includes(node.id) || update(node.child, ids));
}

var data = [{ id: 1, name: "A", isSelected: false, child: [{ id: 2, name: "B", isSelected: false }, { id: 3, name: "C", isSelected: false }] }, { id: 4, name: "D", isSelected: false, child: [{ id: 5, name: "E", isSelected: false }, { id: 6, name: "F", isSelected: false }] }],
    nodes = [{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

update(data, nodes.map(({ id }) => id));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you need to iterate all nested arrays, you could store the flag, iterate and return the result of the iteration.

```js
function update(array = [], ids) {
    if (!array.length) return false;
    var selected = true;
    array.forEach(node => {
        node.isSelected = ids.includes(node.id) || update(node.child, ids);
        selected = selected && node.isSelected;
    });
    return selected;
}

var data = [{ id: 1, name: "A", isSelected: false, child: [{ id: 2, name: "B", isSelected: false }, { id: 3, name: "C", isSelected: false }] }, { id: 4, name: "D", isSelected: true, child: [{ id: 5, name: "E", isSelected: true }, { id: 6, name: "F", isSelected: true }] }],
    nodes = [{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

update(data, nodes.map(({ id }) => id));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This works great, but a little problem it does not mark the nodes unselected if I change the selected  nodes input to empty list